# Getting data from the sqlite db into c# string

Tags: c#, sqlite

I have this code

```
string[] GetFaculties()
    {
        string[] result = { };
        SetConnection();
        sql_con.Open();
        sql_cmd = sql_con.CreateCommand();
        sql_cmd.CommandText = "SELECT kyrname FROM tnames";
        SQLiteDataReader reader = sql_cmd.ExecuteReader();
        int i = 0;
        foreach (DbDataRecord record in reader)
        {
            result[i] = record["kyrname"].ToString();
            i++;
        }
        sql_con.Close();            
        return result;
    }
```

which returns me "No current row" exception for 'foreach'. How do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this :

```
var ordinal = reader.GetOrdinal("kyrname");
while (reader.Read())
    {
        result[i] = reader.GetString(ordinal);
        i++;
    }
```

The read method Advances the SqlDataReader to the next record and while there is a next record.

Comment: Thanks you for help, but I did it another way, since I need to assign size to the 'result' array. http://ideone.com/NeojcL

Comment: Your result array isnt initialized